# Why this this code only output ""? (Codeingame's Thor challenge)

Tags: c++

I need help finding the mistake I have made with an alternative approach through diferences of the x and y values on the Thor-challenge of Codeingame.

Here is the code of the game loop:

```
// game loop
    while (1) {
        int remainingTurns; // The remaining amount of turns Thor can move. Do not remove this line.
        cin >> remainingTurns; cin.ignore();
        int difx = lightX-initialTX;
        int dify = lightY-initialTY;
        float mathquot=dify/difx;
        string out ="";
        if(difx==0 || dify==0){
            if(difx=0){
                if(dify<0) out="W"; initialTY-=1;
                if(dify>0) out="E"; initialTY+=1;
            }
            if(dify=0){
                if(difx<0) out="N"; initialTX-=1;
                if(difx>0) out="S"; initialTX+=1;
            }
        }else{
            if(mathquot>0 && (difx>0 && dify>0)) out="SE"; initialTY +=1; initialTX+=1;
            if(mathquot>0 && (difx<0 && dify<0)) out="NW"; initialTY -=1; initialTX-=1;
            if(mathquot<0 && difx<0) out="SW";  initialTY +=1; initialTX-=1;
            if(mathquot<0 && dify<0) out="NE";  initialTY -=1; initialTX+=1;
        }
        // Write an action using cout. DON'T FORGET THE "<< endl"
        // To debug: cerr << "Debug messages..." << endl;


        // A single line providing the move to be made: N NE E SE S SW W or NW
        cout << out << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that you seem to have a lot of missing braces, presumably because you decided to put multiple statements on one line, so e.g.

```
        if(mathquot>0 && (difx>0 && dify>0)) out="SE"; initialTY +=1; initialTX+=1;
```

should probably be:

```
        if(mathquot>0 && (difx>0 && dify>0)) { out="SE"; initialTY +=1; initialTX+=1; }
```

and so on, for the other similar lines.

---

You also seems to be confusing *assignment* (`=`) with the test for equality (`==`), so lines such as:

```
if(difx=0)
```

should be:

```
if(difx == 0)
```

---

Another problem: you are mixing integer and floating point arithmetic incorrectly. E.g. in this line:

```
float mathquot=dify/difx;
```

you are performing in integer division, with truncation, which is then being converted to a float result. You most likely need:

```
float mathquot=(float)dify/difx;
```

which will force the division to be carried out as floating point.

---

**IMPORTANT: Some of the problems above would have been picked up by your compiler, if you had enabled warnings.** You will save yourself a lot of time and grief if you learn how to enable warnings (e.g. `gcc -Wall ...`), and then take notice of any such warnings at compile-time. If your code compiles "cleanly" (i.e. no warnings) then you should have fewer problems to debug at run-time.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response!